# Application in AKS not work Azure AD Error AADSTS50011

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-authentication

n the AKS, an application was deployed that is authenticating with Azure AD, url is https://corpapps.domain.com/apptool, but we get error AADSTS50011.
"AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://corpapps.domain.com/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application '#clientid'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this."

Our configuration in the application registration URI is this https://corpapps.domain.com/apptool/signin-oidc

And in the appsettings is this:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.com",
    "TenantId": "#Tenantid",
    "ClientId": "#clientid",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-callback-oidc"
}
```

The application is developed in .net core 5 mvc razor, when running local it works, but in AKS it doesn't work.

I appreciate if you can help me with some guidance. Thanks.

I change URI in de register application, in the appsettings change callbackpath, but nothing works

Comment: Hi @Yami: have you resolved this issue ? and how ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For my case, I have .NET 6, and there are only 2 things that I need to do to solve this issue:

- Set ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED to true inside the container
- In the ingress yml, set the ssl-redirect: "true" and header size to 32 kb

ex:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "32k"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: fas-web-app-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

work arounds :

Make ssl redirect to true as ,by default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443  if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.

> This can be disabled globally using ssl-redirect: "false" and with the
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" annotation in the
> particular resource.

So try making them true if it is false in ingress routing yaml file.

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

Also try using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "32k"`  (or 16k) in annotations

There is an ongoing issue regarding this in github . Please check :[application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/300) .

Reference:[create-an-ingress-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli#create-an-ingress-route)

Also as per the document pointed in the error , this error occurs when the user tries to sign in to the application by using OIDC or OAuth2 SSO.
and the resolution for that is given in the same doc: see [Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-redirect-uri-mismatch#resolution)

You can raise a support request for the same if issue doesn't resolve.